# understanding bounding box example in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I was just checking out the **[angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive)** and came across the following example of **[bounding box](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/024-center-bounds-example.html)** , now see the setting for the bounding box , the code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["openlayers-directive"]);
        app.controller("DemoController", [ "$scope", "olHelpers", function($scope, olHelpers) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                offset: 0,
                cairo: {
                    lat: 30.0047,
                    lon: 31.2586,
                    zoom: 10,
                    bounds: []
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch("offset", function(offset) {
                $scope.cairo.bounds[0] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[1] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[2] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[3] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
            });
        }]);
```

I am not quite understanding what exactly is the use of adding bounding box in this example as , even if i take of the bounding off the bounding box settings , nothing really changes. Can anybody explain ?